# Linking to existing javadocs only works for Java Platform packages

Tags: javadoc, java

I've got this class in a file called `test.java`:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;

public class test {
    public ByteBuffer x;
    public ByteBuf y;
}
```

I generate my javadocs like this:

```
javadoc -link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/ -link http://netty.io/4.0/api/ test.java
```

Only links to classes from Java Platform packages are created, there are no links to classes from Netty or other packages I tried:

[image: Javadocs with link option]

How to make javadoc create links to other packages as well?

---

On the man page of javadoc it says that the only file that's really required is the `package-list` file:

> The Javadoc tool reads the package names from the package-list file
>   and then links to those packages at that URL. When the Javadoc tool is
>   run, the extdocURL value is copied literally into the links
>   that are created.

For both links those files are present:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/package-list
- http://netty.io/4.0/api/package-list

It might be relevant that when generating the javadocs without providing any links like this:

```
javadoc test.java
```

Likewise it only shows the package name of the Java Platform package:

[image: Javadocs without link option]

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any javadoc warnings/errors?

On my end, I see:

```
$ javadoc -link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/ -link http://netty.io/4.0/api/ test.java
Loading source file test.java...
Constructing Javadoc information...
test.java:2: error: package io.netty.buffer does not exist
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
                      ^
test.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
    public ByteBuf y;
           ^
  symbol:   class ByteBuf
  location: class test
Standard Doclet version 1.8.0_111
```

If I add the netty jar to javadoc's classpath, the errors go away and my built javadocs include links to `ByteBuf`:

```
$ javadoc -cp netty-4.0.42.Final/jar/all-in-one/netty-all-4.0.42.Final.jar -link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/ -link http://netty.io/4.0/api/ test.java                      
Loading source file test.java...
Constructing Javadoc information...
Standard Doclet version 1.8.0_111
Building tree for all the packages and classes...
```